# I can't access my private data member and function in my operator functions

Tags: c++

I made this short code and I want to know that why I can't access my private data member and 
function in my overloaded insertion & extraction operator even though I can access them from other functions. Can someone please point out the errors for me and explain it to me why is this happening?
Thanks in Advance.
The interface file and implementation file is given below.
Program:-

**Header File**

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cctype>

class  Money {
    long all_cents;
    int digit_to_int(char);
public:
    long getAll_cents();
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const Money&);
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream&, Money&);
    friend Money add(const Money&, const Money&);
    friend bool equal(const Money&, const Money&);
    friend Money operator+(const Money&, const Money&);
    friend Money operator==(const Money&, const Money&);
    Money operator-(const Money&);
    Money(long, int);
    Money(long);
    Money();
    double get_values();
    void setMoney(std::istream&);
    void output(std::ostream&);
};
```

**Source File:-**

```
#include "Money.h"

int Money::digit_to_int(char c) {
    return(static_cast<int>(c) - static_cast<int>('0'));
}
long Money::getAll_cents() {
    return this->all_cents;
}
Money Money::operator-(const Money& amount) {
    Money temp;
    temp = -amount.all_cents;
    return temp;
}
Money::Money(long dollars, int cents) :all_cents((dollars * 100) + cents) {
    if (dollars * cents < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Illegal values for dollars and cents !!!";
        exit(1);
    }
}
Money::Money(long dollars) :all_cents(dollars * 100) {
    if (dollars < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid arguments for dollars!!!";
        exit(1);
    }
}
Money::Money() :all_cents(0) {}
double Money::get_values() {
    return (all_cents * 0.01);
}
void Money::setMoney(std::istream& ins) {

    char one_char, decimal_point, digit1, digit2;
    //digits for the amount of cents
    long dollars;
    int cents;
    bool negative; //set to true if input is negative

    std::cout << "Enter the amount = ";

    ins >> one_char;
    if (one_char == ' ') {
        negative = true;
        ins >> one_char;   //read '$'
    }
    else {
        negative = false;
    }

    ins >> dollars >> decimal_point >> digit1 >> digit2;

    if (one_char != '$' || decimal_point != '.' || !isdigit(digit1) || !isdigit(digit2)) {
        std::cerr << "Error  Illegal form for money input\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    cents = digit_to_int(digit1) * 10 + digit_to_int(digit2);

    all_cents = dollars * 100 + cents;
    if (negative)
    {
        all_cents = -all_cents;
    }
}
void Money::output(std::ostream& outs)
{
    long positive_cents, dollars, cents;
    positive_cents = labs(all_cents);
    dollars = positive_cents / 100;
    cents = positive_cents % 100;
    if (all_cents < 0) {
        outs << "-$" << dollars << ".";
    }
    else {
        outs << "$" << dollars << ".";
    }
    if (cents < 10) {
        outs << '0';
    }
    outs << cents << std::endl;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outs, const Money& amount)
{
    long positive_cents, dollars, cents;
    positive_cents = labs(amount.all_cents);
    dollars = positive_cents / 100;
    cents = positive_cents % 100;
    if (amount.all_cents < 0) {
        outs << "-$" << dollars << ".";
    }
    else {
        outs << "$" << dollars << ".";
    }
    if (cents < 10) {
        outs << '0';
    }
    outs << cents << std::endl;
    return outs;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& ins, Money& amount)
{
    char one_char, decimal_point, digit1, digit2;
    //digits for the amount of cents
    long dollars;
    int cents;
    bool negative; //set to true if input is negative

    ins >> one_char;
    if (one_char == ' ') {
        negative = true;
        ins >> one_char;   //read '$'
    }
    else {
        negative = false;
    }

    ins >> dollars >> decimal_point >> digit1 >> digit2;

    if (one_char != '$' || decimal_point != '.' || !isdigit(digit1) || !isdigit(digit2)) {
        std::cerr << "Error  Illegal form for money input\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    cents = amount.digit_to_int(digit1) * 10 + amount.digit_to_int(digit2);

    amount.all_cents = dollars * 100 + cents;
    if (negative) {
        amount.all_cents = -amount.all_cents;
    }
    return ins;
}

Money add(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    Money temp;
    temp.all_cents = amount1.all_cents + amount2.all_cents;
    return temp;
}

bool equal(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    return (amount1.all_cents == amount2.all_cents);
}

Money operator+(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    Money temp;
    temp.all_cents = amount1.all_cents + amount2.all_cents;
    return temp;
}

Money operator==(const Money& amount1, const Money& amount2) {
    return (amount1.all_cents == amount2.all_cents);
}
```

Comment: What exact verbatim error is the compiler giving you?

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outs, const Money& amount) { amount.output(outs); return outs; }`

Comment: Thanks to @BigBoiBen I have fixed the errors

Comment: @Mehroz did you edit your code after BigBoi posted the answer? I can't find the naked `all_cents` in your friend functions. I feel like I'm going blind.

Comment: Also if an answer answered your question you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

In your **ostream** line number 84 and 87 you should write **amount.all_cents** as you are in a friend fucntion and you cannot access the private data member **all_cents** without the object that is **amount** which you passed in you fucntion.

on line number 83

```
positive_cents = labs(amount.all_cents);
```

on line number 86

```
if(amount.all_cents<0)
```

and the same error occurs in the istream overloaded fucntion as you are trying to access **digit_to_int()** which is also private so you need to access it with the **.** operator through object

on line number 122 - 125

```
cents=amount.digit_to_int(digit1)*10+amount.digit_to_int(digit2);
amount.all_cents=dollars*100+cents;
if(negative)
{
amount.all_cents=-amount.all_cents;
}
```

Do know you cant just magically access private members everywhere you need to have appropriate setters and getters for accessing them orelse what is the use of access modifiers in object orientated programming in c++ if you just want them having accessed anywhere then there is no use of object orientated programming and you will just follow procedural programming , Hope this helps out :)